# how to query different where conditions on same table and joining result

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have table questionbank , I want to extract questions depending on different where conditions such as

```
(SELECT unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD , CorrectAnswer, marks 
FROM questionbank 
WHERE  Department = "DCP" 
and Subject = "CO" 
and Unit = "1" 
and marks = "1" LIMIT 3) 
UNION (SELECT unit,Subject,Question,OptionA ,OptionB ,OptionC ,OptionD ,CorrectAnswer,marks
FROM questionbank 
WHERE  Department ="DCP"  
and Subject="CO" 
and Unit="1" 
and marks ="2" LIMIT 1 )
```

I have 6 units and marks are 1,2,3 or 4. and limit is specified by user.
this will be quiet big query in traditional union way. how to do it in simple and easy way ?

only unit (1to6) , marks (1to4) and limit are variable in this query.

Comment: What is your question?  Your query looks fine.

Comment: i just wrote query for one unit and marks =1 , i have 6 such units and marks 1,2,3,4. how to combine all this together? , using union will make this query very big , whats another efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: Do Department and Subject differ for different units and marks or `Department = "DCP" and Subject = "CO"` clause is a constant?

Comment: department and subject are common.

Comment: units range from 0 to 6 , and marks 1to 4.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand a final goal without data example, but I suppose one of the following variants can be useful.

**Using `IN` operator**

If Department and Subject are constant values, you can use `IN` operator:

```
SELECT unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectAnswer, marks 
FROM   questionbank 
WHERE  Department = "DCP" and Subject = "CO" and Unit IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6") and marks IN ("1", "2", "3", "4")
```

**Different Department and Subject**

```
SELECT unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectAnswer, marks 
FROM   questionbank 
WHERE
    (Department = "DCP" and Subject = "CO" and Unit = "1" and marks  = "1")
    OR (Department = "XXX" and Subject = "YY" and Unit = "2" and marks  = "3")
    OR ...
```

Or you can use some other approach that could be similar to one of the two above.

First of all, you need to decide for yourself, how these 4 parameters (Department, Subject, Unit and Mark) are related each to other. Then it will be much more easier to find an optimal solution.

**Update:**

For different limits for each mark, I suppose something like this can be used:

```
SELECT unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectAnswer, marks 
    FROM   questionbank 
    WHERE  Department = "DCP" and Subject = "CO" and Unit IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6") and marks = "1"
    LIMIT 1
UNION ALL    
SELECT unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectAnswer, marks 
    FROM   questionbank 
    WHERE  Department = "DCP" and Subject = "CO" and Unit IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6") and marks = "2"
    LIMIT 2
UNION ALL    
SELECT unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectAnswer, marks 
    FROM   questionbank 
    WHERE  Department = "DCP" and Subject = "CO" and Unit IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6") and marks = "3"
    LIMIT 3
UNION ALL    
SELECT unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectAnswer, marks 
    FROM   questionbank 
    WHERE  Department = "DCP" and Subject = "CO" and Unit IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6") and marks = "4"
    LIMIT 4
```

However, I can't check this variant right now for correct syntax.

Comment: good answer, let me clear , department and subject are common ,  each unit has 4 types of questions 1,2,3,4 mark questions. each of them having user decided limit.

Comment: It could be used `Unit = "1" and Mark IN ("1", "2", "3", "4")`. However, if there are separate limits for each unit, possibly, a `UNION` will be an optimal solution.

Comment: yes there is different limit for 1 marks...4 mark questions

Comment: So, you can use IN for Unit and 4 unions for each mark. The resulting query will be not so long.

Comment: will you please edit your answer to demonstrate it ? that was my exact question , thank you.

Comment: yes. very close to an answer , thanks. i will post working answer soon. cant  thank you enough.

Comment: @NinadGosavi: You don't have to post the working answer again.. Just upvote..and accept the answer so that the due credit is seen..!

Comment: i did upvote, but it dint count so i posted answer . now i have deleted it. thanks to let me know .

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not clear at all, but you can combine different possible conditions in your `where` with `or`, like

```
SELECT  unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD , CorrectAnswer, marks 
FROM    questionbank 
WHERE   Department = "DCP" and Subject = "CO" and (
          (Unit = "1" and marks = "1") OR
          (Unit = "2" and marks = "3") OR
          /* ... */
          (Unit = "6" and marks = "4")
        )
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: i have to select 1 marks 2 marks 3 marks and 4 marks question from each unit , in total there are 6 units and there is limit to select 1 ,2 3,4 marks questions.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing with MySQL is that it is so flexible and the IN clause can run matches even with multiple expressions. I was not able to find a good documentation about the feature that I am about to explain, but I will try my best to put it simply.

So a usual IN clause works like this:

```
SELECT 
column1,column2,...
FROM
table_name
WHERE 
(expr|column_1) IN ('value1','value2',...);
```

But you can modify the IN clause expression to work with as many expressions you want:

```
SELECT 
column1,column2,...
FROM
table_name
WHERE 
((expr1|column_1),(expr2|column_2),..) IN (('value1','value2'), ('value3','value4')...);
```

I have a simple [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aeb1a/2) demonstrating this.

So to simply answer your question, you can modify your query like this to achieve what you want without over-killing your query with `UNION`.

```
SELECT  unit, Subject, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD , CorrectAnswer, marks 
FROM    questionbank 
WHERE   Department = "DCP" 
and Subject = "CO" 
and (Unit, marks) IN ((1,1), (1,2), (2,3), .. , (6,4))
LIMIT 3
```

I always use it in my queries, but haven't seen a lot of people working with it. I find it the best way to deal with paired combinations in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Happy to help! :)